# After the Smart Guides turned on,

Tags: adobe-illustrator

After the Smart Guides turned on, why does the anchor point on a line actively align the anchor point on a shape path, but the shape path cannot actively align the anchor point on the line?

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE.  Any chance you could post a screenshot showing the problem, or what you are trying to achieve? Illustrator's snapping/smart guides aren't particularly controllable. You might need to employ another method such as using physicall guides.

Comment: I'm afraid you may need to ask Adobe why their "smart guides" are remarkably stupid at times.